# 2 different views in android setContentView

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I need to have 2 different images in one view. The ***GraphicsView(this)*** is supposed to be an animation (actually an image that rotates it self in the center of the view) and ***R.layout.main*** is supposed to be the background of the view (a static image again on the top of the view)

What I need is an imageview on the top of the view and bellow the animation view I have

```
    public class spinball extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
    private static class GraphicsView extends View {
        private Bitmap ball;
            private int XOffset;
            private int YOffset;

        private Animation anim;

        public GraphicsView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ball = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
            XOffset = ball.getWidth() / 2;
            YOffset = ball.getHeight() / 2;
        }
        private void createAnim(Canvas canvas) {
            anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas
                    .getHeight() / 2);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setDuration(10000L);
            anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

            startAnimation(anim);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // creates the animation the first time
            if (anim == null) {
                createAnim(canvas);
            }

            Path circle = new Path();

            int centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            int centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
            int r = Math.min(centerX, centerY);

            circle.addCircle(centerX, centerY, r, Direction.CW);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, centerX - jobsXOffset,
                    centerY - jobsYOffset, null);
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/static_image"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make your question clear. Cant get you properly.

Comment: I included the whole code, hope that explains more.

Answer (score 4):

Use `RelativeLayout`. Later children of the `RelativeLayout` stack "on top of" (Z-axis) earlier children.

Answer (score 0):

An activity can only have one content view. If you want to just have a background image you can set the background drawable of your top level layout, and have that layout contain the ImageView. Is that what you are going for?